# Pointer isn't chaning after function calls in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I have this popFront function for a linked list:

```
Node* popFront(Node* list)
{
    Node* returnMe = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node* oldHead = list;

    returnMe->mData = list->mData;

    if (list->mNext != NULL)
        list = list->mNext;  // This line is definitely called
    else
        list = blankNode;    // And not this one

    free(oldHead);

    return returnMe;
}
```

But whenever I call it like this:

```
Node* list = buildList(10);
Node* oldHead = popFront(list);

printInfo(list);
```

'oldHead' is correct but 'list' still has its first Node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the variable `list` to change, you need to pass it by pointer. Since the value of list is `Node*`, you would need to pass to have the signature of popFront be `Node* popFront(Node **list)`.

Comment: Got it working.  I was confused because I was already passing a pointer but I needed a pointer to a pointer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to read up on the difference between *pass by value* and *pass by reference.* The pointer `list` is passed to the function `popFront()` *by value*, meaning that its value is copied into the local variable in the function. When you change that copy, the original variable outside of `popFront()` is unchanged. If you want to be able to change the value of `list`, then you need to pass a *pointer* to `list` (i.e., pass it *by reference*) and modify `popFront()` accordingly to work with a pointer to pointer to `Node`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler example to understand:

```
void foo(int x)
{
   x = 2;
}

int main()
{
  int x = 3;

  foo(x);
  // if you understand why x is still 3 here,
  // then you'll understand your problem as well.

  return 0;
}
```